# Can you use @types/react v18 with react v17?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to use `@types/react` v18 with `react` v17? Was wondering if it was backwards compatible (?)

Comment: You can see the breaking changes in e.g. https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1800-march-29-2022. It would have to be both backwards _and forwards_ compatible, given that the types will allow your code to use APIs that didn't exist in v17. Why don't you just use the relevant types?

Answer (score 0):

It might work partially, but any function signature that's changed will become misleading - TypeScript will report one thing and the older version of React will expect something else.